# Swift, iOS: Water mirror text lable & image icon

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am getting the table cell in mirrored water image. Please check the screen shots:
[image]

The constraints are: [image]

Comment: It looks like you are applying some type of transform. Show the code you are using.

Comment: yes @DonMag It was kind of transformation. This is resolved. My bad i forgot to update its status. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for the chat window we need to perform some kind of transformation onto table view & the cell. Thats was missing. So I added that & now it is working fine.

For table view the transformation is:

```
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: 0)
```

and inside cellForRowAt:indexPath function I set the same to cell like:

```
cell.transform = tableView.transform
```